# Determine the Kind (int, float) of Number a Python numeric literal represents?

Tags: python, tokenize, standard-library, number-literal

*In case anyone is interested, this is a  followup to [Regular expression to match a Python integer literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733262/regular-expression-to-match-a-python-integer-literal).*

The `tokenize` module is useful for breaking apart a Python expression, but `tokenize.NUMBER` is not very expressive, as it represents all kinds of number literals, for example, `1`, `1l` (in Python 2), `0xf2`, `1e-10`, `1.1`, `0b101`, `0o17`, and `1j` are all considered NUMBER (and also all the previous with uppercase letters).  Is there a function in the standard library that tells me what kind of the above I have?  I particularly care about if I have an integer or a float (complex is also considered float), but further expressiveness would be OK too :).  Basically, I don't want to try to catch all possible number literals myself, as I already managed to do it wrong once.

Comment: The last question you asked (the linked one) already describes how to get the type of number. Call `type(num)` to see if it's a float or int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)?

```
type(ast.literal_eval(s))
```

Comment: same answer as mine and `type` will return `<type 'int'>` for hex, oct, and bin however

Comment: Should work for what I need, though.  I guess I need to check `type(ast.literal_eval(s)) not in (int, long)`.

Comment: Or isinstance I guess would be better.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I need it to work in Python 2.5, which doesn't include ast.  But I think it should be safe to use regular `eval()` if I know the input is a `tokenize` NUMBER.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse any Python number format down to an int, float, or long:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('1')
1
>>> ast.literal_eval('1l')
1L
>>> ast.literal_eval('0x2')
2
>>> ast.literal_eval('0b1101')
13
```

Bear in mind that there is no 'hex' or 'oct' or 'bin' type in Python. Those literal strings are immediately converted to their decimal equivalents.

This works pretty well:

```
def numtype(s):
    numtypes=[int,long,float,complex]

    try:
        n=ast.literal_eval(s)
    except SyntaxError:
        return None

    if type(n) not in numtypes:
        return None  
    else:
        return type(n)    

for t in ['1','0x1','0xf2','1e-10','0o7','1j', '0b1101']:
    print t, numtype(t)
```

Prints:

```
1 <type 'int'>
0x1 <type 'int'>
0xf2 <type 'int'>
1e-10 <type 'float'>
0o7 <type 'int'>
1j <type 'complex'>
0b1101 <type 'int'>
```

If you really need to differentiate between the different decimal types, you could do something like:

```
def numtype(s):
    numtypes=[int,long,float,complex]

    try:
        n=ast.literal_eval(s)
    except SyntaxError:
        return None

    if type(n) not in numtypes:
        return None    

    if type(n) != int:
        return type(n)
    else:
        if 'x' in s.lower():
            return 'HEX'
        if 'o' in s.lower():
            return 'OCT'   
        if 'b' in s.lower():
            return 'BIN'     

        return int
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_int(number_string):
    try:
        i = int(number_string)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: But has to be duplicate/repeated for `int`, `long`, `float` .. any more unified method? Also, does this work for octal/hex notations (or is there an assumed base)?

Comment: @asmeurer, sorry - I wasn't aware that `int()` didn't do the full set of integer literals. I wonder if there's an equivalent which does? Looking at the other answers I guess that's what `ast.literal_eval` does.

Comment: It does, but you have to pass it the base in the second argument.

Comment: @asmeurer that kind of defeats the purpose of having the base encoded in the literal.

Comment: Yeah.  I guess it's so you can do it for other bases, and also where it isn't in the literal (like `int('10', 2)` or `int('21', 3)`). I totally agree, but I didn't write it.  I guess the logic is that it's `int(n, base=10)`, so that the base if not given defaults to 10.